# Lenovo Tablet Wont Turn on

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, lenovo

So, I have a Lenovo A7-50 A3500F (Not rooted). And when I was reading through Facebook it randomly turned off. I thought nothing of it (Battery was on 97%, I had just charged it). When I tried to turn it back on, the lenovo screen flashed on but then turned off again. I tried to go to recovery mode and wipe the EMMC card but that also failed. Is the tablet useless or is there something I can do about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u have already restarted it you should take it into the shop u got it from and see if they can fix your tablet in anyway if the people there cannot fix then u will have to get a new one or if your insurance covers it you will be okay so good luck with your tablet :)